# Make paragraph height 100%

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to make the height of the paragraph 100%, but when I try it doesn't do it. Setting the size in pixels does work. What I have:

```css
*,
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  list-style: none;
}

.infoDiv {
  height: 50%;
  background: grey;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.textStart p {
  height: 100%;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="infoDiv">
  <div class="imgStart col-xs-12 col-sm-7"></div>
  <div class="textStart col-xs-12 col-sm-5">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: The solution is giving it the ViewHeight (vh).

Comment: you have infodiv at 50% ??

Comment: My given solution should solve what you're trying to achieve as height of paragraph being 100% to the remaining height of the body left. And its funny how people downvote even if the answer is correct.

Comment: 100% of what? 100% of its parent, of the window, …?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the working code

```css
*,
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  list-style: none;
}

.infoDiv {
  height: 50%;
  background: grey;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.textStart p {
  height: 100vh;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="infoDiv">
  <div class="imgStart col-xs-12 col-sm-7"></div>

  <div class="textStart col-xs-12 col-sm-5">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Since, the text is vertically aligned it pushes the paragraph text further down to the point where you have to scroll to view it. 100vh has to be applied to the parent div if needed be. And if the paragraph is going to use half the body of the viewport, then it should be 50 not 100.

Answer (score 0):

In CSS3 you could use

`height: calc(100% - 60px);`